# does the ag-grid api support column filtering drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable, ag-grid

in datatables it supports Individual column searching (select inputs). 
[(datatable)](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html). Does ag-grid support similar functionality apart from filter column by typing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, ag-grid does not support it "out-of-the-box". In free version only filtering of type "number" and "text" is supported. In paid, enterprise version, there is also a filter for type "set", but there is only multiple selection.  However, there is a possibility to write a custom filter. The examples are shown under the "Custom Column Filtering" subchapter [Link to the custom ag-grid filters](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/index.php)

p.s. Wanted to leave a comment, because actually this is not really an answer, but does not have enough repo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ag grid has an api gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter but it will be applied across the grid

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AgFloatingFilterComponent } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { IFloatingFilterParams } from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
  selector: 'number-component',
  template: `<select
      style="width: 100%"
      [(ngModel)]="currentValue"
      (ngModelChange)="onChange()"
    >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let c of options" [ngValue]="c">{{c}}</option>
    </select>`,
})
export class OptionFilterComponent
  implements AgFloatingFilterComponent {
  params: IFloatingFilterParams | undefined;
  currentValue: Number | null | string = null;
  style: any;
  options: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.options = params.options;
  }

  onParentModelChanged(parentModel: any) {
    // When the filter is empty we will receive a null value here
    if (!parentModel) {
      this.currentValue = null;
    } else {
      this.currentValue = parentModel.filter;
    }
  }

  onChange() {
    if (!!!this.currentValue) {
      // Remove the filter
      this.params?.parentFilterInstance((instance: any) => {
        instance.onFloatingFilterChanged(null, null);
      });
      return;
    }
    this.params?.parentFilterInstance((instance: any) => {
      instance.onFloatingFilterChanged('equals', this.currentValue);
    });
  }
}
```